# Массив в обратном порядке PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день! С формы ввода должны отразиться предложения в обратном порядке. К примеру, ввели:
Предложение один. Предложение  два. Предложение три. Предложение четыре.
Должно отобразиться:
Предложение четыре. Предложение три. Предложение два. Предложение один.
Смогла найти такое решение:

```
 //Разбиваем строку в массив по разделителю '.':
 $arr = explode('.', $a);

 //Получим предл в нужном формате:
 echo $arr[2].'.'.$arr[1].'.'.$arr[0];
```

Подскажите, как отразить результат, если предложений будет много (неизвестное количество)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу свое решение с использованием замечательной функции [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php) для деления текста на массив строк по определенному правилу:

```
<?php
$text = 'Предложение один.   Предложение два.Предложение три. Предложение четыре.  ';
var_dump($text);
$arr = preg_split('%(?<=\.)\s*%', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($arr);
$arr = array_reverse($arr);
var_dump($arr);
$text = implode(' ', $arr); 
var_dump($text);
```

То есть делим по точке (при этом точка остается в конце отделяемого предложения) и пробелам (если они есть за точкой), которые удаляются - `%(?<=\.)\s*%`

Результат:

```
string(134) "Предложение один.   Предложение два.Предложение три. Предложение четыре.  "
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "Предложение один."
  [1]=>
  string(30) "Предложение два."
  [2]=>
  string(30) "Предложение три."
  [3]=>
  string(36) "Предложение четыре."
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "Предложение четыре."
  [1]=>
  string(30) "Предложение три."
  [2]=>
  string(30) "Предложение два."
  [3]=>
  string(32) "Предложение один."
}
string(131) "Предложение четыре. Предложение три. Предложение два. Предложение один."
```

**P.S.** Решение лишено недостатков варианта с использованием explode().

**P.P.S.** Если в конце текста будут символы отличные от `\s`, они встанут в начало результирующего текста, как начало нового первого предложения :)

```
string(137) "Предложение один.   Предложение два.Предложение три. Предложение четыре.  111"
-->
string(135) "111 Предложение четыре. Предложение три. Предложение два. Предложение один."
```

Answer (score 4):

[array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reverse.php) - разворачивает массив

[implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) - объединяет элементы в строку, через разделитель.

Вариант кода из вопроса будет выглядеть так:

```
echo implode(".", array_reverse($arr));
```

Но сама задача может оказаться сложнее: недостаточно просто разделить строку по точке. Во-первых, точка не всегда значит конец предложения, во-вторых, пробелы после нее потеряются.

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = '';
for ( $i=count($arr)-1; $i>=0; $i-- ){ // идем от последнего элемента массива к первому
   $s = $s.'.'.$arr[$i]; // добавляем элемент к результату
}
$str = substr($str, 1); // удаляем первую точку
echo $str; // выводим результат
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_reverse($arr)
```

> array array_reverse ( array array [, bool preserve_keys] )
>
> Функция array_reverse() берёт массив array и возвращает новый массив,
>   порядок элементов в котором обратный исходному, сохраняя ключи, если
>   параметр preserve_keys равен TRUE.